# Unable to load onnx model in UWP project on Windows build 19041 but it works on Windows build 18363

Tags: uwp, windows-machine-learning

I get ArgumentException with message "Failed to load model with error: Unknown model file format version." when try to call LearningModel.LoadFromStreamAsync(stream) on Windows build 19041. It works fine with the same file on build 18363. ONNX opset 7.

Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

I converted my keras model to onnx model with new version of keras2onnx. It helped me to successfully load new model file.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Machine-Learning/issues/360) from the Windows Machine Learning GitHub repo:
"There was a version check that was added in 19041 that may be causing this. Older version would potentially permit model versions that they didn't understand, which is why some models worked, but it couldn't be guaranteed to work so we needed to add the version check."